# Rutas de formularrios de laravel no se convierten https

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy desplegando un proyecto y ya tiene certificado pero las rutas de los formularios siguen http lo cual hace que el navegador lo tome como un sitio inseguro.

asi es como esta el dominio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y asi es como se ve el formulario en el doom.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y en el código tengo la ruta asi.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

### Opcion 1

Si cuenta con CPANEL debe tener la opcion de forzar respuesta https

### Opcion 2

En su archivo de configuracion de laravel .env debe editar la variable

```
APP_URL=https://
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero no cuento con CPANEL y las configuración del env  ya esta:(

Comment: Cual version de laravel utilizas?